# How to show foreign characters in ggplot output in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, markdown

I am currently working on a paper with ggplot plots which includes Turkish characters in labels.
When I knit this RMarkdown file, Turkish characters such as "ğ" and "ı" are seen as "." in the plots.

```
ggplot(cars,aes(x = speed, y = dist))+
  geom_point()+
   labs(x = "Hız")
```

when I knit this chunk there is a warning `## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :## conversion failure on ’Hız’ in ’mbcsToSbcs’: dot substituted for <b1>` and the output is [image: output of the ggplot].

I tried to put the HTML codes of the characters in to labels but it also didn't work.
[image: plot with html code]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way using `ggsave` and `\includegraphics`. (**PDF** **output**)

````
---
title: "rmd2023"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex      
date: '2023-04-11'
---       

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r cars, include=F, warning=F}
ggplot(cars,aes(x = speed, y = dist))+
  geom_point() +
   labs(x = "H\u0131z") 

ggsave("Turk.png", dpi = 300)
```

\includegraphics{Turk.png}
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could use unicode:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "2023-04-09"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r cars}
ggplot(cars,aes(x = speed, y = dist))+
  geom_point()+
   labs(x = "H\u0131z") # Unicode for "ı" is '\u0131'
```
````

[image]

Comment: still shows "h.z " in PDF output with the same error. HTML output is fine.

Comment: Will check for pdf!

Comment: I tried with pdf. For me it also does not work. I guess the issue is that some fonts may not have the required characters, such as the dotless "i" (ı) in the PDF. Maybe with `extrafont` it could work. Good luck.